# How to remove 'Resource temporarily unavailable" on sendto()

Tags: c, sockets

The program communicates with 4 microcontroller devices using a single UDP socket and `sendto()`. The `sendto()` function is called on every iteration of a main program loop to update the controllers on the status of the program.

It is okay if I am sending only to 1 device. But, if I try sending to 4 devices, I very frequently get `EAGAIN` errors, to the point that communication is not possible.

How can I remove these errors? I cannot make the socket blocking, as it would slow down the entire program, which needs to handle a lot of other functions almost instantaneously.

I could send the `sendto()` messages less frequently, but I still would like 2-3 300byte messages a second to each device.

If I were to use `select()`, there is the added problem of ensuring each device gets an equal share of the socket.

```
main_loop {
    open_chamber_socket();
    while (!sig_received) {
        unsigned char * buf;
        for (keydata_poll = 0; msgsize < 0 && errno == ENOMSG && !must_term; keydata_poll++) {
            if ((keydata_poll % 12) == 0) {
                deferred_activities();
            }
            msgsize = msgrcv (msgqid
                , (struct msgbuf_s *)msg, MSGTEXTSIZE (msg)
                , MSGID_KEYDATA, IPC_NOWAIT);
            if (msgsize >= 0)
                break;
            usleep(500);    
        }
        if (msgsize < 0) {
            if (errno != EINTR) {   // report any error except a termination signal
                log_perror(MYNAME ": Error receiving queued message.");
                usleep(5 * 1000);
            }
            continue;
        }
        switch (msg->mtext.action) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

```
deferred_activities() {
    ... 
    two thousand lines of code which bit by bit build the send buffers
    ...
    int j, code;
    for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
        struct sockaddr_in addr = {.sin_family = AF_INET, .sin_port = htons(4096)};
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = device[j]->net_address;
        addr.sin_port = device[j]->net_port;
        code = sendto(e_socket, device[j]->buf, device[j]->datasize, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof addr);
    }
}
```

```
int open_chamber_socket(void)
{
    int code, flags;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int optval = 1;
    
    e_socket = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (e_socket < 0) {
        log_perror (_("%s: Can't create chamber socket."), MYNAME);
        return e_socket;
    }
    // set non-blocking flag on the socket ..
    flags = fcntl (e_socket, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags != -1)
        fcntl (e_socket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
        
    setsockopt(e_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval));
    bzero((char *) &addr, sizeof addr);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (CHAMBER_ADDRESS);
    addr.sin_port = htons (CHAMBER_PORT);
    code = bind (e_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof addr);
    if (code < 0) {
        log_perror (_("%s: Can't bind chamber socket to 10.0.0.1:%d."), MYNAME, CHAMBER_PORT);
        return code;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

System: Debian Linux bullseye

Comment: Use `select()` or `epoll()` to wait for the socket to be ready to write to.

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing what else your code is supposed to do and what timing requirements you have. Instead of the fixed `for` loop, use a round-robin index that is incremented only if sending was successful and kept at its previous value on `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`. I don't know if a socket per device would help.

Comment: If you're worried about fairness with `select/poll`, you could keep a per-device linked list of request blocks that point to the messages you want to send (e.g. `struct req { void *data, size_t len; }`). And, a struct (e.g) `struct devstatus { size_t total_sent, total_pending; struct timespec time_of_last_send; struct req *requests; }` for each connection. When the socket is "ready", you can search your device list to find the "oldest" `time_of_last_send` and/or largest `total_pending`. Or, some mix of those. You can also do something similar for the receive side.

Comment: Is the socket non-blocking?

Comment: @n.m. OP: _I cannot make the socket blocking as it would slow down the entire program ..._

Comment: Don't know your environment/OS, but on linux, you can use `PACKET_MMAP` and/or [relatively new] `io_uring`. Separate sockets for each device may help (e.g. more _kernel_ resources per each socket).

Comment: What is the network device you're using (e.g. ethernet, UART, etc.)? For ethernet, 900 bytes/sec for a given destination (up to 4) should be trivial. Please edit your question and post _more_ of your code. Initialization, buffer sizes, structs, etc. would be of interest.

Comment: I am using Ethernet. The 300-byte packets aren't sent once a second, but once a loop iteration - so possibly up to hundreds of times or more a second

Comment: We really need to see more of your code. With the scheme I suggested (`struct req; struct devstatus;`), it should be able to handle much higher throughput (I've used such a scheme before). If your outer loop is doing a lot more than the sends, you may _not_ want `select` but do what you're doing and not "pop" a request on `EAGAIN`. That is, you don't want to delay the non-send/calculation code with `select`. You want the "sleep" time of `select` to be used for calculation. When you do `sendto` with `EAGAIN` check you are "polling"

Comment: posted some more code to clarify the timing

Comment: What's the value in `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default`?  You're probably filling up your socket send buffer.  Use larger buffers and a separate socket for each device as others have already noted.  Oh, and **count how many packets you send  and compare it to how many each device receives**.  You don't have **any** flow control, and if there's a problem anywhere, your packets will be **dropped**.  "Dump and hope" is not a good UDP transfer algorithm.

Comment: You can send it to a broadcast address and everyone will receive it. Use coroutines, lol.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes indeed, I increased those to a recommended size I saw online (25 MB), and it works flawlessly. Not sure if there would be any unintended consequences though.

Comment: @user1095108 good idea but unfortunately the data for each device is slightly different

Comment: I almost forgot: take a look at [UDT](https://github.com/dorkbox/UDT).

Comment: interesting, I haven't heard of it and it doesn't appear to have widespread adoption despite its potential for high speed transfers.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the Linux OS UDP buffers resolves this conflict.
In /etc/sysctl.conf, I set both read and write buffers to 1 MB default and 25 MB max:

```
net.core.rmem_max = 26214400
net.core.rmem_default=1048576

net.core.wmem_max = 26214400
net.core.wmem_default = 1048576
```

Comment: try zmq, or some other mq library.